# Cleaning up code with generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am somewhat new to Generics and I came across this issue, I have repetitive code that I am trying to clean up. The signature is different but the code being executed is the same, is there a way to pass in a generic type instead of having to specify each type in a new signature?

```
public JsonResult<JsonData> GetServiceData(Func<IServiceResponse<IEnumerable<Order>>> func)
{
    var response = func();
    var jsonDataContainer = Mapper.Map<JsonData>(response);

    var result = GetJsonResult(jsonDataContainer);

    return result;
}

public JsonResult<JsonData> GetServiceData(Func<IServiceResponse<List<int>>> func)
{
    var response = func();
    var jsonDataContainer = Mapper.Map<JsonData>(response);

    var result = GetJsonResult(jsonDataContainer);

    return result;
}

public JsonResult<JsonData> GetServiceData(Func<IServiceResponse<User>> func)
{
    var response = func();
    var jsonDataContainer = Mapper.Map<JsonData>(response);

    var result = GetJsonResult(jsonDataContainer);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to answer this question definitively, because you haven't specified the signature of `Mapper.Map`.

But, if `Mapper.Map` can take an `IServiceResponse<T>` of any type `T`, then this would work.

```
public JsonResult<JsonData> GetServiceData<T>(Func<IServiceResponse<T>> func)
{
    IServiceResponse<T> response = func();
    var jsonDataContainer = Mapper.Map<JsonData>(response);

    var result = GetJsonResult(jsonDataContainer);

    return result;
}
```